# Rounded corners on Divs. Problem with Internet Explorer only!

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

Has anybody experienced any problems with creating rounded corners on Divs? I am using the jQuery plugin from http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

The problem is that the top corners are not rounding in Internet Explorer. Works fine with Firefox! Anybody got any advice?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#panel").corner("10px");
        });

</script>
```

Here's the div that gets rounded:

```
<div ID="panel">test</div>
```

Comment: There is always problem with IE only... ;)

Comment: can you show the css for the "panel"..?

Comment: Which version of IE are you having a problem with and does the plug-in page display all the options correctly?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>IE does not support HTML5 or CSS3, so looking at [this test page which you supplied](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) it is clear that it will not work in IE because the examples on this page modify CSS properties which IE is not designed to handle.</strike>

EDIT: After looking at the example again (in IE this time, as I should have the first time) thanks to the comment, I have no idea why your thing is broken in IE.

Comment: The plugin handles IE, or should...that's the point of the plugin :) Visit the test page in IE to see.

Comment: I see that now, you got me there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems getting any IE rounded corners code to work on a background that wasn't solid.

In the end I had to go with a .gif solution.

This will be supported in IE9.

Comment: Read: it will be "supported" in IE9, maybe correctly supported by IE11 :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with using that plugin. I ended up using class selectors to do it:

`$('.header_box').corner("top round 10px")`